# Group Location Transform Problem

Tags: modeling, groups

See the One Drive link below.  I have a group object in a scene called "Lib" in file "AssetsIssue.blend".  The model simply consists of a group of cylinders representing shoulder, elbow and wrist joints for a Remote Manipulator.  These objects are supposed to be arranged at set offsets from the origin and set rotations.  The master group is called "RMS".  I instance RMS on another scene called "Compose".  There is an error seen in image "LibScene-LocationBad.PNG" - the wrist joint at the upper left is separated from the arm cylinder.

The problem; is that when I fix this offset in the master group by block selecting the offending components and translating them in x to the proper offset, the locations revert to the original bad offsets as soon as I go to the scene named "Compose" and Add->Group Instance the RMS group.  See images "LibScene-Edited.PNG" and "ComposeScene-LocationBad.PNG"

Note in the screen shots "LibScene-LocationBad.PNG" and "LibScene-Edited.PNG"  the location, scale and rotation transform boxes are green. They remain green even if I remove all the members from the group.

What am I doing wrong?

[Links to shared files on One Drive](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqqF0GPQHlmzgb0vVsDo3KQV56HwsQ)

Comment: How are you linking said groups, as group Instances? Are the objects animated? Is the position keyframed somewhere? Is the current scene at frame zero? Moving animated objects without keyframing positions will result in loss of transforms.

Comment: No, nothing is animated yet, this is a static model.  The way I am adding the instance to the Solar Array scene is with "Add->Group Instance"

Comment: Please post some screenshots of your scene and object settings, or provide a as **simplified as possible** [file reproducing the problem](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) Use the edit link bellow your question

Comment: Ok, look for a simpler file with a simpler model that also has the problem, and screenshots showing how to replicate the problems

Comment: As I mentioned animated objects will always revert  to their keyframed positions. Your objects have green transform properties buttons, meaning they are keyframed. Cleanup your scene and remove undesired animations.

Comment: I do have a camera path animation in the file, on a layer where I had deleted all the object instances.  That's probably where the keyframes come from.  Thanks for confirming the problem.